# What type of normal form when having parent child table contain some equal columns?

Tags: database, oracle

I have two relations

*RP(ID,CODE,MSG,TEXT)* with Primary Keys *ID* and *CODE* and
*RC(ID,CODE,LANGUAGE,MESSAGE,TEXT)* with a Primary Key made of *ID*,*CODE* and *LANGUAGE* and Foreign Keys *RC.ID*->*RP.ID*, *RC.CODE*->*RP.CODE*

RP contains a redundant example message and text in any language that would otherwise only be stored inside RC (combined to a certain language key) if I weren't be forced to have an example text for readability in the first table.

(In before: I know I could handle this with a view combining both, still I am kinda forced to do this because the framework I use needs to display tables as they are.)

So my exact question is: **which normal form is the first table (RP) in**? (I think it's at least first, because all attributes are atomic, and it's indifferent what the child table contains.)

Answer (score 0):

For second normal form (as I recall) you eliminate repeat groups.  So for RP, it sounds like MSG and TEXT would be an example of a repeat group.  Therefore, I would say it is in first normal form.

If they are not repeat groups, then it is at least second normal form.

For third normal form (as I recall) you eliminate partial dependencies and transitive dependencies.  I don't think there are dependencies, so if it's 2nd normal and no dependencies, then it is 3rd normal as well.

Comment: Well the both columns are just there for readability. I could enter a completely other text, it's just that I'll copy the first translation I get (probably English) into the first table, all other translations will be stored in the second table (the English one probably not, because it would be kind of pointless).

Comment: @C.Scholz, then I'd say it is at least 2nd normal form, and maybe even 3rd normal.  I'm glad you are interested in data normalization, most applications I encounter (I'm on a team that supports over 300 prod.  Oracle instances and over 2000 app's) seem to have been developed with little or no concern doe normalization.  I learned the tricks of the database design trade back in the mid '80's, and we took normalization very seriously.   Interestingly, a lot of the database design skills transferred right over to object oriented designs (which added behavior (i.e. the methods)).